# Order database results by bayesian rating

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm not sure this is even possible, but I need a confirmation before doing it the "ugly" way :)

So, the "results" are posts inside a database which are stored like this:

- the posts table, which contains all the important stuff, like the ID, the title, the content
- the post meta table, which contains additional post data, like the rating (`this_rating`) and the number of votes (`this_num_votes`). This data is stored in pairs, the table has 3 columns: post ID / key / value. It's basically the WordPress table structure.

What I want is to pull out the highest rated posts, sorted based on this formula:

> br = ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) )
>    / (avg_num_votes + `this_num_votes`)

which I stole form [here](http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating).

`avg_num_votes` and `avg_rating` are known variables (they get updated on each vote), so they don't need to be calculated.

Can this be done with a mysql query? Or do I need to get all the posts and do the sorting with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Stack Exchange Link:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2137/order-database-results-by-bayesian-rating

```
SELECT id,title,( AVG(this_num_votes) * AVG(this_rating) + this_num_votes * this_rating )
     / ( AVG(this_num_votes) + this_num_votes ) as br
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT post_id,
(SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE postmeta.post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key ='this_num_votes') as this_num_votes,
(SELECT meta_value FROM postmeta WHERE postmeta.post_id = pm.post_id AND meta_key ='this_rating') as this_rating
FROM postmeta pm ) as newmeta ON posts.ID = newmeta.post_id
GROUP BY id,title,this_num_votes,this_rating
ORDER BY br DESC
```

Comment: `this_num_votes` and `this_rating` are not column fields, but records. Those names are record values in the `key` column.

Comment: for example this query would get all posts that have rating/votes meta keys: `SELECT * postmeta LEFT JOIN posts ON (posts.ID = post_id)  WHERE meta_key IN('this_rating', 'this_num_votes') $order_here LIMIT 0,10`

Comment: That's amazing, thank you :) Only one small mistake, the br formula is incorrect, it should be `(($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating)) / ($avg_num_votes + this_num_votes) as br`. The average vote and rating is global, not relative to the current post

Comment: since * have higher priority i think they are same

Comment: Yes, I wasn't referring to the order of operations, but to the value of `AVG(...)` which is wrong. The average vote/rating is calculated for all posts, and it's a php variable :)

Comment: since database handle it you dont need php to handle average

Comment: You do, because your average is the post's average rating. The formula needs a global average rating, from all posts from the database.

Comment: Rather old question - but if someone is interested, check my updated answer below, without the use of PHP and the correct function.

Answer (score 1):

here it's a start to go:

```
// Bayesian Rating Calc
$theItem = $_GET[’id’];
if($theItem) {
// all items votes and ratings
$result = mysql_query(”SELECT AVG(item),AVG(vote) FROM itemvotes WHERE vote>’0′ GROUP BY item”) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$avg_num_votes = $row[0];
$avg_rating = $row[1];

// this item votes and ratings
$result = mysql_query(”SELECT COUNT(item),AVG(vote) FROM itemvotes WHERE item=’$theItem’ AND vote>’0′”) or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$this_num_votes = $row2[0];
$this_rating = $row2[1];

if(!$row OR !$row2)
$br = “_”;
else
$br = number_format( ((($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating))/($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes)), 1, ‘.’ );
} // end of if item selected
```

Answer (score 1):

I have altered the accepted answer's data and query.

The data is now a sample of a data from a 5 star rating system.
The function now correctly uses average values of all the posts.

The difference is in the calculation of those average values, instead PHP, they are calculated in the SQL, for the purpose of the answer.

<s>You can see it in action on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84d8b/2/2</s>

---

### The updated query

The new fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cdfe/1/2

```
SET @avg_total_votes  := (SELECT AVG(meta_value) FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key ='this_num_votes');
SET @avg_total_rating := (SELECT AVG(meta_value) FROM postmeta WHERE meta_key ='this_rating');

SELECT  posts.ID,
        posts.title, 
        getmeta_votes.meta_value AS votes,
        getmeta_rating.meta_value AS rating,
        ( ( (@avg_total_votes * @avg_total_rating) + (getmeta_votes.meta_value * getmeta_rating.meta_value) ) / ( @avg_total_votes + getmeta_votes.meta_value ) ) AS factor
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN postmeta AS getmeta_votes  ON posts.ID = getmeta_votes.post_id  AND getmeta_votes.meta_key  = 'this_num_votes'
LEFT JOIN postmeta AS getmeta_rating ON posts.ID = getmeta_rating.post_id AND getmeta_rating.meta_key = 'this_rating'
WHERE NOT getmeta_votes.meta_value = 0 AND NOT getmeta_rating.meta_value = 0
ORDER BY factor DESC;
```

I have found this query construction to be much faster, the previous one was working for 2 hours on a 2,000+ posts data set (1,000,000+ wp_postmeta rows), until terminated.

This one runs in 0.04 sec.

Comment: This doesn't work well with my real data set (a WordPress database with several thousands of posts) and I will optimize the query and update my answer in a while.

Comment: Ok, the query is now updated and working pretty well. I hope this will help someone and spare some time that I had to spend on it. Cheers!